# Connection to MongoDB server using Node is unresponsive on localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am trying to connect my node.js game to a MongoDB cluster so that I can store username and passwords. I already have the a mock DB stored locally using express + socket.io. I am trying to set up MongoDB atlas to store the usernames + passwords so that when the local host closes, the data won't disappear.

I've tried the following [Developing A RESTful API With Node.js And MongoDB Atlas](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/09/developing-restful-api-nodejs-mongodb-atlas/) word for word. When I test my connection if it was successful, I enter on terminal:

```
node app.js
```

My server starts as expected and prints `server started`. From this tutorial, I should either see an error or a successful connection message. However, when I start the server, I don't see either. I am having trouble debugging this because I am not getting any response at all.

Here is the beginning of my app.js file for context.

```
// Express code
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app); 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const CONNECTION_URL = *uri here* 
const DATABASE_NAME = "bunnyCrossing";

var timeRemaining; 
// If query is '/' (nothing)
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

// If query is '/client'. Client can only request things from client folder
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client')); 

// replace the uri string with your connection string.
var database, collection;

app.listen(3000, () => {
    MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        collection = database.collection("people");
        console.log("Connected to `" + DATABASE_NAME + "`!");
    });
});
// Server starts listening on port 2000
serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started");
```

I should see when I run node app.js:

```
server started
Connected to `bunnyCrossing`!
```

But I just see:

```
server started
```

Comment: Are you sure your server listen to success? `console.log` after `serv.listen` don't make sure that your server is running, try move `console.log("Server started");` to a callback of `app.listen`. Try change port 200 to other port.

Comment: @Hongarc When I fix the console log and go to localhost 2000, the server starts and prints correct meessage. When I change port 3000 to port 2000, a server error is thrown ""Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::2000". I know this means port 2000 is in use, so I'm just confused what port Mongo should be on.

Comment: You just run `serv.listen` or `app.listen`, don't run both of all.

`app.listen`  don't have mean that you choose port for `MongoClient`
You don't need one more port to run `MongoClient`, MongoDb server do it, and you config port to conect in `CONNECTION_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Either `app.listen` is not being called or you must hit `localhost:3000` to invoke the callback to connect to mongo database.

Either remove `serv.listen` or add a callback to `serv.listen` as such and remove `app.listen`.

```
serv.listen(2000, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        collection = database.collection("people");
        console.log("Connected to `" + DATABASE_NAME + "`!");
    });
  }
})
```